# How to exchange data between bamboo task and a microservice

Tags: continuous-integration, task, microservices, bamboo, data-exchange

**I want to send a file from Atlasssian Bamboo task to a microservice hosted online.**

**My microservice will process the file and send back some metrics to bamboo task which invoked it.**

*1) How exactly can i send my file from bamboo task to a URL. (I can create a microservice which accepts post with a payload.)*

*2) How can we send back the data from microservice to the same Bamboo task.*

*3) Will the bamboo task wait till it receives data back from the microservice?*

I want a general direction how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable but will require either third party plugins or some heavy scripting.

You can create a script file that:

1. Sends a build artifact or file to the URL.
2. Reads a response from the URL.
3. Blocks until this is accomplished.

The script file can be a Powershell script, Python script, or really anything that does the above.  I would strongly recommend looking for any [third party plugins](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/addons/app/bamboo) that do some or all of what you are trying to accomplish though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding.How do you block this task until the response is received from the microservice

Comment: @NiharSuryawanshi: Lots of languages will block and wait for a response (and you can usually set a timeout).  While inefficient you could even go so far as to have a powershell script "Sleep" for a set period of time and then try and process the response it should be getting back.